# inconsistency between `.live()` and `.autocomplete()`

Tags: jquery

In the following code, `.live()` don't work, but `.autocomplete()` does. Why? (See http://jsfiddle.net/fRpCy/1/)

```
var input = [];
input.push($('input'));

$(input).live('keydown', function (event) {
    console.log('You have pressed a key!');
});

$(input).autocomplete({ source: ['test1', 'test2'] });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.live()` query-object method operates on queries that are fundamentally selectors.  `$([$('input')])` is not a selector query, it's a query over an array containing a selector query.

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> ... the `.live()` method should always be called directly after a selector ...

---

<sup>Copied from my comment below:</sup>

`.autocomplete()` works because it operates more in line with other jQuery functions, which enumerate the objects provided by the query and act on them immediately.  `.live()` does not *enumerate*, but rather *inspects* the query at a later time -- whenever any event is fired.  Since the query is not in the form it is expecting, it simply ignores it.

Comment: We are not talking about the `$.live()` function here. We are talking about the `.live()` function.

Comment: @cdhowie has the right answer, if you change it to $("input").live( you'll see that it works

Comment: There is no $.live, the answer is referring to $.fn.live and is correct.

Comment: @Both: That is not my point! I'm not trying "to make it work". I'm trying to understand why the two functions react differently to the same object.

Comment: @Randomblue: Did you even check the rest of the answer before downvoting to see if it works, or do you downvote purely because of pedanticism?  Nevertheless, I have corrected the (rather minor) error.

Comment: @cdhowie: I downvoted because I (still) feel you are not answering the question. You have explained why `.live()` doesn't work. But why does `.autocomplete()` work? I can always change my vote later.

Comment: @Randomblue: Then you should have said that instead of focusing on an insignificant detail.  `.autocomplete()` works because it operates more in line with other jQuery functions, which enumerate the objects provided by the query and act on them.  `.live()` does not *enumerate*, but rather *inspects* the query whenever any event is fired.  Since the query is not in the form it is expecting, it simply ignores it.

Comment: Actually, I just made a small remark and you interpreted that as the reason of my downvote, and made a fuss out of it. Anyway, thank you for your time, I get it now. +1

Comment: Yes, because I usually expect people to comment when they downvote, and that was the only existing comment on the answer at the time.  It was reasonable for me to assume that the only critical comment on a question with one downvote would be the reason for said vote.  Please don't interpret my response as angry -- I was really just astonished at my perception of the situation.  Glad I could help.  Your question is a good one, and I'm honestly not sure why it was downvoted.  :/

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` works by waiting for an event to bubble up to the `document`.  Then it compares `event.target` to the selector to determine whether or not it should run the callback function.  Since you are providing an object and not a selector, it has nothing to compare so it won't run the callback.  `live()` does not look at the object itself except to get its selector.

`.autocomplete()` operates directly on the provided jQuery object and does refer to the selector.